# Ajax ожидаение окончания запроса

Tags: ajax

```
$('.form-dynamic').on('click', '.save-this-row', function(){
        var btn = $(this);
        var form = btn.parents('form').serialize();
        var depId = btn.parents('.for-clone').data('dep-id');
        var data = depId != undefined ? form + "&id=" + depId : form;
        var parentItem = $(this).parents('.item');

        $.ajax({
            url : '/settings/departments',
            method : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            data : data,
            success : function(data){
                if(data.message == 'success'){
                    $('.validation-error').removeClass('validation-error');
                    btn.parents('.for-clone').attr('data-dep-id', data.id);
                    parentItem.removeClass("active");   
                    parentItem.addClass("edited");  
                }else{
                    $.each(data, function(key, value){
                        if(value != ''){
                            parentItem.find('.'+key).addClass('validation-error');
                        }else{
                            parentItem.find('.'+key).removeClass('validation-error');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По кликаю посылаю запрос на сохранение данных в бд,приходит успешный ответ,после чего кнопка должна исчезнуть,но появляется так что она исчезает не сразу и в этот момент юзер еще кликов 5 может сделать по ошибке,не зная что еще не завершился запрос.Как реализовать ожидание пока все выполнится? разве `success` это не реализует?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прячьте кнопку до вызова `$.ajax`

```
parentItem.removeClass("active"); // это что ли?
$.ajax({
  ...
```

и показывайте опять если надо

```
success : function(data){
  if(data.message == 'success'){
     ...
  }else{
    parentItem.addClass("active");
    ...
  }
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    parentItem.addClass("active");
    ...
}
```

Другой подход:

```
var ajaxRunning = false;
$('.form-dynamic').on('click', '.save-this-row', function(){
  if (ajaxRunning)
    return;

  ...
  ajaxRunning = true;
  $.ajax({
    ...,
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      ajaxRunning = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Тогда будет получаеться так,жму кнопку валидация не прошла а кнопка уже спратяна,так не пойдет!

Comment: Вы хотите узнать результат действия до того как это действие завершилось? Так не пойдет!

Comment: Сперва интересует вопрос почему ответ уже пришел от запроса,а действие все еще не выполнилось,с чем это связано

Comment: Какое действие? Такое чувство, что Вы не совсем правильно интерпретируете то, что происходит. "Ответ пришел" - это начал выполняться обработчик `success`?

Comment: @quaresma89, вы уверены, что ответ пришел? Ajax-запрос не выполняется моментально.

Comment: Извиняюсь это я уже туплю перед сном голова не варит.Да success отрабатывает как положено.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете перед отправкой ajax-запроса делать кнопку неактивной:

```
btn.prop('disabled', true);
```

А если запрос вернул ошибку, возвращаете активность кнопке:

```
btn.prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: Вот так и попробую спасибо